# PyTest teardown_class is being run too soon

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pytest, teardown

The Python "teardown_class" is not behaving as I expect it to. Below is a summary of my code:

```
@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
    cls.create_table(table1)
    cls.create_table(table2)
    cls.create_table(table3)

@classmethod
def create_table(cls, some_arg_here):
    """Some code here that creates the table"""

def test_foo(self):
    """Some test code here"""

@classmethod
def teardown_class(cls):
    """Perform teardown things"""
```

### I believe the way it is executing is that:

1. create_table is being called from setup with 1st parameter (table1)
2. Code in create_table executes
3. Code in teardown_class executes
4. 1-3 above is executed again with the 2nd parameter
5. 1-3 above is executed again with the 3rd parameter
6. Code in test_foo executes

### How I expect it to perform:

1. create_table is called with 1st parameter (table1)
2. Code in create_table executes
3. create_table is called with 2nd parameter (table 2)
4. Code in create_table executes
5. create_table is called with 3rd parameter (table 3)
6. Code in create_table executes
7. Code in test_foo executes
8. Code in teardown_class executes

Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.6.2, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. I recreated the `create_table` function as an **inner** function, inside of the `setup` function.

```
@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
    def create_table(some_arg_here):
       """Some code here that creates the table"""

    create_table(table1)
    create_table(table2)
    create_table(table3)

def test_foo(self):
    """Some test code here"""

@classmethod
def teardown_class(cls):
    """Perform teardown things"""
```

And now it runs as I expect it to, in this sequence:

1. Run `create_table` once for table1 param
2. Run `create_table` once for table2 param
3. Run `create_table` once for table3 param
4. Run `test_foo`
5. Run `teardown_class`

It seems that any/every time a function that is outside of `setup` is called from `setup`, it causes the `teardown` function to run **directly after** the code in the outer function runs, and that was the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Your classmethod misses the cls param:

```
@classmethod
def create_table(some_arg_here):
    """Some code here that creates the table"""
```

Change it to

```
@classmethod
    def create_table(cls, some_arg_here):
```

I modified your code and added some prints:

```
class TestClass:

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        print("Setting up")
        cls.create_table('table1')
        cls.create_table('table2')
        cls.create_table('table3')

    @classmethod
    def create_table(cls, some_arg_here):
        print("Creating:", some_arg_here)
        """Some code here that creates the table"""

    def test_foo(self):
        print('Running test_foo')
        """Some test code here"""

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        print("Tearing down")
        """Perform teardown things"""
```

If you run it with -s you will get the following result:

```
test.py Setting up
Creating: table1
Creating: table2
Creating: table3
Running test_foo
.Tearing down
```

As you can see, everything works as expected. The setup_class is called, tables are created (all 3), test method runs and then teardown_class kicks in.

If you add a function test_bar() you will get:

```
test.py Setting up
Creating: table1
Creating: table2
Creating: table3
Running test_foo
.Running test_bar
.Tearing down
```

Seems also to be fine to me..

Do you have some more hints for your assumption something is wrong?

Comment: I've come to find that the issue occurs when I call another method from the setup method. If I put the code from create_table directly into the setup method, it works as expected: all the code in the setup method runs, then the test, then the teardown. But if I call create_table from setup (multiple times), then after each call, it runs teardown. Is this really how it's expected to perform? If so I need a workaround...