# teardown_class is running right after setup

Tags: python, class, pytest, teardown

I have code similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62289822/14303498
Now I added similar fixture "teardown_class". when I execute my code. Teardown_class is executed right after setup_class

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
def setup_class(self, connect_db_fixture_from_conftest):
    print("\n ********* we are inside setup")
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s.%s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )"
    DBHelper.execute_query(self,sql,connect_db_fixture_from_conftest)
   
def test_db(self, connect_db_fixture_from_conftest):
    print("**** inside test *********")
   
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
def teardown_class(self, connect_db_fixture_from_conftest):
    print("\n ********* we are inside teardown")
    sql = "DELETE from table_name where key=value"
    DBHelper.execute_query(self,sql,connect_db_fixture_from_conftest)
```

Output from test is:

```
********* we are inside setup
********* we are inside teardown
**** inside test *********
```

I want:

```
********* we are inside setup
**** inside test *********
********* we are inside teardown
```

I tried this suggestion also but no luck https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089177/14303498

Comment: Add a `yield` as first line in `teardown_class`. See [Fixture finalization / executing teardown code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. It workd with yield in teardown_class

Comment: However I am seeing following error though in my code I see there is no direct calling of the fixture ```Fixture "teardown_class" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.```

Comment: Don't call fixtures directly (as regular functions). Only use them as test function arguments.

Comment: @hoefling, Can you please be more specific? Hear is my teardown_class 
```@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
def teardown_class(self, connect_db_fixture_from_conftest):
    print("\n ********* we are inside teardown")
    sql = "DELETE from table_name where key=value"
    DBHelper.execute_query(self,sql,connect_db_fixture_from_conftest)```

Comment: Looks for places in code where you invoke the function, like `teardown_class()` etc.

Comment: I did not have teardown_class anywhere else in the code. However changing teardown_class to teardown_module fixed the issue. Though I dont know the reason behind it.

Comment: That's because naming a fixture `teardown_class` clashes with another plugin that runs nosetests. `pytest` has builtin support for running tests written with `nosetest` which reserves names `setup_class`, `teardown_class`, `setup_method`, `teardown_method`, `setup` and `teardown` for special functions that will be invoked automatically. You can disable this plugin explicitly: `pytest -p no:nose`, but it's easier to give the fixture a more meaningful and less abstract name.